# Name changed due to illness - Does this necessitate a new Kesuba?

Tags: halacha, names, choleh-sick, ketubah

A man or a lady were ill and a name was added to their previous name. Would there be a need to write a new Kesuba? Is the Halacha the same by a man who has an added name as by a woman who has an added name? (sources)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Dinonline.org](http://www.dinonline.org/2012/02/13/new-name-for-kesubah/):

> The Question:
>
> If someone is lo aleinu sick and adds a name to his existing name does he have to have written a new Kasubah?
>
> Answer:
>
> The Iggros Moshe ([Choshen Mishpat 2:70:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=921&st=&pgnum=298)) writes that if a person is not called by his new name, one does not write a new kesubah after a name was added due to illness. This is also the ruling given by Shut [Ohel Avraham 67](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=342&pgnum=118).
>
> If the new name is used, a new kesubah should be written (according to the principles of writing a new kesubah (with the words “after a new name was added), after thirty days of the new name being used (see [Minchas Yitzchak 10:132](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1601&pgnum=495); the principle of waiting thirty days is based on the ruling of the Noda Biyhuda EH 88; see see Chasam Sofer 6:41).