# changing one's Hebrew name

Tags: halacha, names

Sometimes a sick person changes his Hebrew name or adds to it.

Is there a problem (halachically or otherwise) with changing one's Hebrew name, for someone who is not sick? For example, he prefers a different name for whatever reason.

I am especially interested in halachic problems with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Halacha a person has the right to change his name to whatever he or she likes.

But the Minhag is not to do so without a valid reason, and only after consulting a prominent Rabbi, due to many complications that could arise in result of that, and for other reasons as well.

source: Kobetz Ginas Verdim[image]

Answer (score 6):

One of the senior Rabbis in Israel - [Rav Chaim Kanievsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Kanievsky) (son of the famous [Steipler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yaakov_Yisrael_Kanievsky) Gaon) - occasionally changes people's names.

This is often done when their Biblical names come from wicked people - like [Nimrod](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nimrod).

A friend of mine - a scion of a Rabbinic family - was told to change his name from Amir to Meir. (The reason given by Rav Chaim was that Amir was animal food; though we have not been able to find a source for this.)

We see in the Chumash that Hashem renamed Abram to Abraham and Sarai to Sara and Yaakov to Yisrael - even though they were not ill.

Other biblical figures also had multiple names. For example [Moses - as mention on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moses#Judaism):

> Moses' other names were: Jekuthiel (by his mother), Heber (by his father), Jered (by Miriam), Avi Zanoah (by Aaron), Avi Gedor (by Kohath), Avi Soco (by his wet-nurse), Shemaiah ben Nethanel (by people of Israel). Moses is also attributed the names Toviah (as a first name), and Levi (as a family name) (Vayikra Rabbah 1:3), Heman, Mechoqeiq (lawgiver) and Ehl Gav Ish (Numbers 12:3).

Conclusion: There does not seem to be a Halachic issue with changing one's name, but I have not found any primary sources for this assertion.

That said, I assume there are Halachic implications when changing one's name - like when writing Gittin - a Get has to have the accurate name(s) of both spouses to be valid.

Comment: Re "Halachic implications" see e.g. http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/35342.

Comment: Re the animal food: Likely R. Chaim was referencing the *mishna* on [Shabbos 76a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=76&format=pdf): "עמיר כמלא פי טלה".

Comment: there is a gemora on yoma where the amoraim deduce that certain people are wicked due to their name having a wicked connotation. perhaps Rabbi Chaim is basing himself on that. my question is what about if someone simply prefers a different name. can he change it to whatever he wants.

Comment: and by himself.

Answer (score 3):

The Mishna in [Gittin 4:2](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01125.html#HtmpReportNum0022_L2) indicates that it was common practice for people to change their names to nullify a bill of divorce.

> בָּרִאשׁוֹנָה **הָיָה מְשַׁנֶּה שְׁמוֹ** וּשְׁמָהּ, שֵׁם עִירוֹ וְשֵׁם עִירָהּ. וְהִתְקִין רַבָּן גַּמְלִיאֵל הַזָּקֵן שֶׁיְּהֵא כוֹתֵב, אִישׁ פְּלוֹנִי וְכָל שֵׁם שֶׁיֵּשׁ לוֹ, אִשָּׁה פְלוֹנִית וְכָל שׁוּם שֶׁיֵּשׁ לָהּ, מִפְּנֵי תִקּוּן הָעוֹלָם

Comment: I'm not convinced that's a proof. See the bartenura there that says: בָּרִאשׁוֹנָה הָיָה מְשַׁנֶּה שְׁמוֹ וּשְׁמָהּ. כְּשֶׁהָיוּ לוֹ שְׁנֵי שֵׁמוֹת, אֶחָד כָּאן וְאֶחָד בִּמְדִינַת הַיָּם, הָיָה מְגָרְשָׁהּ בַּשֵּׁם הַנּוֹהֵג בִּמְקוֹם כְּתִיבַת הַגֵּט, וְלֹא הָיָה מַקְפִּיד לִכְתֹּב אֶת שְׁנֵיהֶם:  (ר"ע מברטנורה). - and the rest at http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01128.html#HtmpReportNum0022_L2

Comment: or see Rashi on the gemara - http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00939.html#HtmpReportNum0065_L2 -  מתני' בראשונה היה משנה שמו ושמה. כשהיו לו שני שמות אחד כאן ואחד במדינת הים היה מגרשה בשם הנוהג במקום כתיבת הגט ולא היה מקפיד לכתוב שניהם:

Comment: @DannySchoemann that is an ukimta in the gemarah based on one opinion

Comment: and where is another opinion, and what does it say? (There are only 2 opinions on this Gemoro, neither of them seem to match your interpretation.)

Comment: @rikitikitembo  BOMBSHELL!