# Replacement kesubah but the father had a name change

Tags: halacha, names, ketubah

I heard an interesting question but didn't hear the answer. There are laws about what to do when someone loses their Kesubah. They write something new called a *kesubah d'irkesa*, which is a document which states that the original was lost and proceeds to write what the original said.

What should be written if a person's father's name was changed between the son's wedding and the writing of this new Kesubah? Should they write the original name, since that's what the original Kesubah said? Or should they write the new name for the father, to properly identify the husband? Also, the lien the wife has on the property starts from the writing of the new Kesubah, so perhaps we should use the current name and not the old one.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/35348/1739, although that's discussing if the husband's own name was changed. Not sure if the law is different if their father's name was changed. In any event, they didn't write a new Kesubah.